# OTP - Server Internal Error

Tags: opentripplanner

When I began to start the OTP server using the command

```
java -Xmx2G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --build /home/username/otp --inMemory
```

The program executes normally and says: Grizzly server running.

But, when accessing
    http://localhost:8080/
it gives me "Internal Server Error"

```
Jar file was not found
 1: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.CLStaticHttpHandler.getJarFile(CLStaticHttpHandler.java:349)
 2: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.CLStaticHttpHandler.handle(CLStaticHttpHandler.java:288)
 3: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:188)
 4: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:219)
 5: org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 6: org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 7: java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Help with this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I -think- it was caused for me by playing around with the --basePath or --graph settings and was unable to correct it from the command prompt.
And according to [a question my Google-fu turned up](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentripplanner-users/b15MZc5ZJM0) it came about due to a space in the file name; which is related to file path.

I fixed the issue by moving the OTP folder up the file structure and running it all from there (as I didn't have any spaces I could remove in the directory names).